# How can I group on a dynamic rounded value?

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting no results in php, but I can see my query is returning multiple rows in phpMyAdmin; the thing that looks strange to me is that phpMyAdmin says 'showing rows 0-0' in phpMyAdmin even when many rows are shown.  My main need is to get the data of each row in php.

I'm working with poker data in tables 'metrics' and 'hands'.

metrics has one row per nickname with 3 relevant columns.  Example...
nickname, AggPct, numHands

```
john, 0.3276, 160
mike, 0.4752, 200
saul, 0.4781, 100
```

hands has one row per poker hand with 2 relevant columns.  Example...
opponentNickname, netSmallBets

```
john, 7
john, 4
john, 9
mike, 8
mike, 2
saul, 20
```

I want a new intermediate table made from hands and metrics to look like this:
nickname, netSmallBets, AggPct, numHands

```
john, 20, 33, 160
mike, 10, 48, 200
saul, 20, 48, 100
```

Then I want a final table (the final results I need) to look like this:

```
ev, numHands, AggPct
0.125, 160, 33
0.1, 300, 48
```

...where 'ev' is the sum of netSmallBets for a group of same AggPct, divided by sum of numHands in that group.  i.e. mike and saul (10+20)/(200+100) = 0.1, and john is in his own group 20/160 = 0.125

The query I have is this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(h.netSmallBets)/SUM(m.numHands) ev, 
SUM(m.numHands) numHands, 
m.AggPct 
FROM 
(SELECT nickname, ROUND(100*AggPct) AggPct, numHands FROM metrics) m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT opponentNickname, SUM(netSmallBets) netSmallBets FROM hands GROUP BY opponentNickname) h 
ON m.nickname=h.opponentNickname 
GROUP BY m.AggPct
ORDER BY m.AggPct ASC
```

It seems to work, except that my php document isn't getting any rows returned (I put a counter in the while loop that gets rows, and it never gets hit).  When I run the exact same query in phpMyAdmin SQL prompt, it says 'Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total...', but then it shows results like this...

```
ev, numHands, AggPct
0.60810810810811, 74, 9
1.6666666666667, 9, 17
1.6666666666667, 6, 19
2.8333333333333, 6, 20
0.74213836477987, 159, 21
-0.37777777777778, 45, 22
```

I need to be able to do some post-processing on each row individually in my php.  Thanks for any help to be able to do this, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Show your PHP code. Is it checking for errors from the mysql query?

Comment: My PHP code is not relevant I'm sure, but here it is, just getting rows for that query, but x never increments: $result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$x++;

Comment: There's no good reason why a query that works when run by hand would fail from PHP, and the usual reason is that the script is not constructing the query correctly. Have you echoed `$query` to see if it's correct? You're also not checking for errors from `mysql_query()`.